# Azure devops powershell gives different result than local powershell on the same query

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have this postDacPac file in project which runs during deployment process. It has a stored procedure in it which can throw an error sometimes. I created a mock stored procedure which has a similar structure below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #tmpSproc
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        print 'Enter sproc';
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            print 'Rollback in sproc.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END;
        THROW 60000, 'Temp error.', 0

END
GO
```

In postDacPac file I use this sproc like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

IF 1=1 /* It is called in an if condition so I kept the structure same. */
BEGIN
    EXEC #tmpSproc;
END
GO

IF @@ERROR <> 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Rollback after sproc.'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Creating error entry'
    INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
    VALUES                  (1);
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
END
ELSE
    PRINT N'sproc succeeded or skipped.'
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors)
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Rollback after deployment.'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT N'success'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT N'fail'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
DROP PROCEDURE #tempSproc
GO
```

I run this on powershell with this script:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString "myConnectionString"  -Inputfile "C:\***\PostDacPac.sql" -QueryTimeout 6000 -Verbose -ErrorVariable errors
```

On powershell it works as I expected. Even though stored procedure throws an error and rolls back, query continues until the end and prints script is failed.

However, when I try this deployment on azure devops pipeline (vsts), if sproc fails, deployment also fails. This is how azure powershell calls this file:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "***" -Database "***" -Username "***"  -Password ****  -Inputfile "D:\***\PostDacPac.sql" -QueryTimeout  6000 -ConnectionTimeout 120
```

I tried to check all the pipeline settings in azure devops but couldn't find a difference. What I might be missing in this scope?

Comment: Have you tried the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell for AzureDevOps / VSTS? It runs local on the build / release host that you get. It might work for your scenario...

Comment: Did you try unchecking the checkbox `Fail on Standard Error?`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these today. I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that after query time-out somehow script runs again. Apparently, it's a known issue. There are also several questions related to this issue like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4167226-2da7-49ec-a5c2-60e964785c2c/powershell-invokesqlcmd-calls-stored-procedure-second-time-after-query-timeout-is-expired?forum=sqldatabaseengine